# Stripe and Firestore

Tags: node.js, firebase, google-cloud-firestore, firebase-admin

I am trying to get Stripe server code working using Firestore. I found example server code that uses Firebase RTDB and am having trouble converting this code to use Firestore.

Original Firebase Function code using Real Time Database:

```
const functions = require('firebase-functions')
const admin = require('firebase-admin')

admin.initializeApp(functions.config().firebase);

const stripe = require('stripe')(functions.config().stripe.testkey)



exports.stripeCharge = functions.database
                                .ref('/payments/{userId}/{paymentId}')
                                .onWrite(event => {



  const payment = event.data.val();
  const userId = event.params.userId;
  const paymentId = event.params.paymentId;


  // checks if payment exists or if it has already been charged
  if (!payment || payment.charge) return;

  return admin.database()
              .ref(`/users/${userId}`)
              .once('value')
              .then(snapshot => {
                  return snapshot.val();
               })
               .then(customer => {

                 const amount = payment.amount;
                 const idempotency_key = paymentId;  // prevent duplicate charges
                 const source = payment.token.id;
                 const currency = 'usd';
                 const charge = {amount, currency, source};


                 return stripe.charges.create(charge, { idempotency_key });

               })

               .then(charge => {
                   admin.database()
                        .ref(`/payments/${userId}/${paymentId}/charge`)
                        .set(charge)
                  })


});
```

My attempt to convert this to using Firestore:

```
const functions = require('firebase-functions')
const admin = require('firebase-admin')

admin.initializeApp(functions.config().firebase)

const stripe = require('stripe')(functions.config().stripe.testkey)

exports.stripeCharge = functions.firestore
  .document('/users/{userId}/payments/{paymentId}')
  .onWrite(event => {
    const payment = event.data
    const userId = event.params.userId
    const paymentId = event.params.paymentId

    // checks if payment exists or if it has already been charged
    if (!payment || payment.charge) return

    return admin.firestore
      .document(`/users/${userId}`)
      .get()
      .then(snapshot => {
        return snapshot
      })
      .then(customer => {
        const amount = payment.amount;
        const idempotency_key = paymentId  // prevent duplicate charges
        const source = payment.token.id
        const currency = 'usd'
        const description = 'irl Map Fine Print'
        const charge = {amount, currency, source}

        return stripe.charges.create(charge, { idempotency_key })
     })
     .then(charge => {
       admin.firestore
        .fieldValue(`/users/${userId}/payments/${paymentId}/charge`)
        .set(charge)
     })
   })
```

My version fails with error saying that admin.firestore.document is not a function.

Comment: What's you firebase version?

Comment: As @OrDuan says, be sure to use `firebase-admin` SDK 5.4 or later: https://github.com/firebase/firebase-admin-node/releases/tag/v5.4.0

Comment: I believe I am using the latest versions: Firebase 4.8.1 and Firebase-admin 5.6.0. I'm getting this from my package.json file.

Answer (score 4):

This updated code will work for you! There were several issues with your code: Missing parentheses... incorrect use of fieldValue (though I am not sure how to use this correctly)... 'document' should be 'doc'

But this works:

```
const functions = require('firebase-functions')
const admin = require('firebase-admin')

admin.initializeApp(functions.config().firebase)

const stripe = require('stripe')(functions.config().stripe.token)

exports.stripeCharge = functions.firestore
  .document('/users/{userId}/payments/{paymentId}')
  .onWrite(event => {
    const payment = event.data.data()
    const userId = event.params.userId
    const paymentId = event.params.paymentId

    // checks if payment exists or if it has already been charged
    if (!payment || payment.charge) return

    return admin.firestore()
      .doc(`/users/${userId}`)
      .get()
      .then(snapshot => {
        return snapshot
      })
      .then(customer => {
        const amount = payment.price * 100 // amount must be in cents
        const idempotency_key = paymentId  // prevent duplicate charges
        const source = payment.token.id
        const currency = 'usd'
        const description = 'irl Map Fine Print'
        const charge = {amount, currency, source}

        return stripe.charges.create(charge, { idempotency_key })
     })
     .then(charge => {
       admin.firestore()
        .doc(`/users/${userId}/payments/${paymentId}`)
        .set({
          charge: charge
        }, { merge: true })
     })
   })
```